# How can I check if input has specific letters in a specific index position in python?

Tags: python

I want to write an encryption programm that changes the input letters to numbers.
What I already achived is that for example if the first letter of the users input is an a (or any other letter) it prints out its connected number .But I couldnt do it with a loop so I had to do this:

```
letter_1 = "a"
if (Text[0])== letter_1 :

print("20")
if (Text[1]) == letter_1:

print("20")
```

I did this with every letter in the alphabet but i have no idea how to use a loop although it would make everything easier.

So in conclusion my problen is that i have to copy the entire alphabet and always change the (Text[]) number so the user can input 1 more letter.

Comment: Just loop over `Text` and compare every character it gives you against `letter_1`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, like a lot problems it helps to break it into steps.  In this case, you start with plain text, which you need to process a character at a time to convert to encrypted text.

Here is an example for the first 4 letters in the alphabet that may help you solve the larger problem:

```
# A dictionary to convert a letter into a (string version of a) number
encoder = {"a": "20", "b": "30", "c": "40"}

# The text to be encrypted
plain_text = "bbca"

# A loop to map the plain_text to encrypted_text
encrypted_text = ""
for plain_char in plain_text:
    encrypted_text = encrypted_text + encoder[plain_char]

print(encrypted_text)
```

Output:

```
30304020
```

Answer (score 0):

First and most importantly, don't use handmade encryption for situations where data security is actually important - make sure this is either for an assignment or a pet project, and not mission-critical.

As for accomplishing your task, you could start with a dictionary that acts as a sort of lookup table, something like

```
enc = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  # Continue through the alphabet, including capital letters, spaces, symbols, etc.
}
```

From there, you could get a string from your user, and then to translate it, you could call

```
encrypted = [enc[letter] for letter in user_input_string]
```

You'll probably run into issues with characters you haven't put into the `enc` dictionary, so be sure to make it as full as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the code to solve your problem, but ideally you should do some basics on looping and data structures like dictionaries and list. I would refer you to HackerRank, it has basic tutorial. You would find it very helpful

```
## Importing randint to generate random numbers
from random import randint

## Create an empty dictionary to store character to number mapping, for example, a -> 21
encoding = {}
## Create a loop that runs 26 times
for i in range(26):
   ## convert 'a' to it's ORD form this is similar to ASCII and can be used to increment alphabets. Add the iteration number to the ORD value and convert it back to char
   key = char(ord('a') + i)
   ## Store the the encoding for the key, for example 'a'. The encoding will be a random number between 0 and 99
   encoding[key] = randint(99)

## Take user input
user_input = input('Enter a string to be encoded')
## Initialise the encoded message as an empty string
encoded_message = ''
## Create a loop that runs for the number of characters in the input string
for i in range(len(user_input)):
    ## Convert the character to lower case
    ch = lower(user_input[i])
    ## Find the mapping in encoding using get, it will return '' if no mapping is found for example if anything other than a alphabet is present.
    encoded_char = encoding.get(ch, '')
    ## Add the encoded char to the message
    encoded_message += encoded_char
## Print the encoded mesaage
print(encoded_message)
```